# Firebase preventing data fetch even though read rules are assigned

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I'm trying to fetch data in the front-end using `firebase`. Here's how my rules are applied to the realtime database:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            ".indexOn": "username",
            "$userId": {
                ".indexOn": "username",
                ".read": "$userId==auth.uid",
                ".write": "$userId==auth.uid",
                "favorites": {
                    ".indexOn": "thumb"
                }
            }
        },
        "files": {
            ".indexOn": ["uploadId", "uploadedBy", "fileURL"],
            "$fileId": {
                ".write": "newData.child('uploadedBy').val() == auth.uid",
                ".read": "data.child('uploadedBy').val() == auth.uid",
                ".indexOn": "fileURL"
            }
        },
        "uploads": {
            "$id": {
                ".write": "newData.child('createdBy').val() == auth.uid || data.child('assignedModeratorId').val() == auth.uid",
                ".read": "data.child('createdBy').val() == auth.uid || data.child('assignedModeratorId').val() == auth.uid"
            },
            ".indexOn": ["createdBy", "status", "assignedModeratorId"]
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what one `uploads` document looks like:

[image]

I'm using this function:

```
const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref('uploads').orderByChild('createdBy').equalTo(uid).limitToLast(1000).once('value');
```

But I keep getting `Error: permission_denied at /uploads: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.` error in the front-end. It's working fine when I use `admin` in the cloud functions. What's wrong with my set rules?

Comment: The Admin SDK bypasses security rules, so testing against that won't help debug the problem. The next thing to check is to make sure that your user is logged in and `uid` has a proper value when you perform the query.

Comment: @samthecodingman Yes the user is logged in and the `uid` has a proper value, I rechecked this and made sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tries to read data from `/uploads`, but your rules don't grant anyone permission to read from that node - so it rejects the read.

If you want to allow the user to read the uploads they created, your rules should [validate that query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules) with something like:

```
"uploads": {
  ".read": "auth.uid !== null &&
            query.orderByChild === 'createdBy' &&
            query.equalTo === auth.uid"}
```